# Parallelization is not working as planned in SSIS

Tags: ssis, parallel-processing

I have a master package that has 4 sequence containers that contain an Execute SQL task that gets a package list consisting of the name of a package to execute and a for each ADO enumerator that enumerates through the list of packages to execute.  Each package is executed using a execute package task.  So my question is why when this is run on the server, only two of the sequence containers are actively executing whereas the other two remain dormant?  Shouldn't all four of the containers be executing at once?  This is why I built the package this way in the first place. Each sequence container has up to 38 packages that it enumerates through evenly.  So for the four containers, each of them execute 38 packages via the loop. So I would expect each container to be executing on the server but it is apparent that they are not.  I only see two packages being executed at once.

Comment: Can you show us what your Control Flow looks like? Also, check the MaxConcurrentExecutables setting in your master package. By default this property is set to -1, which means that the package can run Total Tasks=Number of processors+2.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that setting and I have left it at the default because I am running on a 4 processor machine.  I can add a print screen of my SSIS package for you to review if I can figure out how to do so using the StackOverflow UI.  Basically though, the master package consists of 4 sequence containers that each consist of a SQL Task that retrieves a partial package list and then a for each enumerator that enumerates over the package list and then finally a execute package task that executes an import file task.